# A special 1st order partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $v(x,y)$ be a differentiable function of two variables. What is the solution to the following differential equation :

$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,t)\right)_{x=t} = g(t)v(t,t)+f(t)$$

Comment: I have formatted your question, but you should add some missing details if you want any help. Who is $f$ here ?

Comment: Sorry, the right hand side should read g(t)v(t,t) + f(t)

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} =v(t,t)+f(t)$$
An obvious particular solution is $-f(t)$

Then let : $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-f(t)$ and put it into the equation :
$$\left(\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} = \left(\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} = \left(u(t,t)-f(t)\right)+f(t)$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} = u(t,t)$$
To apply the method of separation of variables, let $u(x,t)=g(x)h(t)$

$$\left(g'(x)h(t)\right)_{x=t} = g(t)h(t)$$
$$g'(t)=g(t)$$
$g(t)=c\:e^t$ any variable symbol, hense $g(x)=c\:e^x$
$$u(x,t)=c\:e^x h(t) = e^x F(t)$$
with $F(t)=c\:h(t)$. Hense :
$$v(x,t)=e^xF(t)-f(t)$$
any function $F(t)$

Comment: Sorry,  I forgot a coefficient g(t) in front of v(t,t) on the right hand side. The equation should read \[frac{\partial}{\partial}v(t,t)= g(t)v(t,t) + f(t)

Answer (score 0):

Since the wording of the question was changed, the answer is different. I don't want to delete the first answer because it continues to be useful.

In order to avoid confusion between the different cases, I prefer to post a separate answer.

$$\left(\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} =g(t)v(t,t)+f(t)$$
An obvious particular solution is $-\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$

Then let : $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ and put it into the equation :
$$\left(\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} = \left(\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} = g(t)\left(u(t,t)-\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}\right)+f(t)$$

$$\left(\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)_{x=t} = g(t)u(t,t)$$
To apply the method of separation of variables, let $u(x,t)=G(x)H(t)$

$$\left(G'(x)H(t)\right)_{x=t} = g(t)G(t)H(t)$$
$$G'(t)=g(t)G(t)$$
$G(t)=c\:e^{\int g(t)dt}$ any variable symbol, hense $G(x)=c\:e^{\int g(x)dx}$
$$u(x,t)=c\:e^{\int g(x)dx} H(t) = e^{\int g(x)dx} F(t)$$
with $F(t)=c\:h(t)$. Hense :
$$v(x,t)=e^{\int g(x)dx}F(t)-\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$$
any function $F(t)$